# Text on multiple lines without spaces as string literals

Tags: javascript, formatting, photoshop-script, ecma

I want to be able to create a variable to hold several lines of text which is then created in Photoshop. My code that creates the text works fine. But I've a problem with my code formatting:

```
var content = "Gwen\r\
               is\r\
               bananas!\r";
```

However, after I process the text it comes out as this:

[image: Gwen is Bananas! text]

Notice the introduction of the whitespace on the second and third line. I don't want to have to format my code on the left like this to remove the string literal spaces.

```
var content = "Gwen\r\
is\r\
bananas!\r";
```

In my code, how can I break up/format the text over several lines **without** having to left justify the text?  Avoiding introducing any further whitespace characters?

[image: text over several lines with no extra whitespaces]

Comment: I think you need to go with `content.trim()` if you wish to init the string that way

Comment: Old-school `+` concatenation is the only way to have complete control of what's in the final string result. Or you could take a radically different approach and import the content from some external source, like a plain file or some kind of catalog system.

Comment: @DiegoD trim is not available as function with Photoshop scripting (ECMA ver 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you. You can use template literals. This solution include placing backticks **`**. One before the string and one at the end of String. Here's the code:

```
var content = `Gwen
is
bananas!`;
```

You can also use string concatenation by applying **+** after each line. Here's the code:

```
var content = "Gwen" +
"is" +
"bananas!";
```

*Note: You can use single quotes too.*

Comment: "without having to left-justify the text" means that the OP wants to avoid putting the second and third lines at the left edge of the source text. The old-school `+` approach is really the only way to do it.

Comment: Did you found my answer really helpful? If yes so please upvote.

Comment: Having to align the text on the left (think if it's nested three tabs over)  is something that I wanted to avoid, but breaking up the string into separate lines joined with + may be the only option.